# Why does `discord.utils.sleep_until` sleeps forever?

Tags: python, datetime, discord.py, sleep

I have defined a periodic task in a Cog that does something every 60 seconds. I want that task to start at the very beginning of a minute, so I added a `before_loop` decorator to it.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext import tasks
import datetime

class Fanfare(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.fanfare.start()

    @tasks.loop(seconds=60)
    async def fanfare(self):
        print('do something')

    @fanfare.before_loop
    async def fanfare_before_loop(self):
        await self.bot.wait_until_ready()

        # Compute the next minute
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        next_minute = now.replace(second=0, microsecond=0) + datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)

        # Troubleshooting
        print(now)
        print(next_minute)

        # Await until next minute
        await discord.utils.sleep_until(next_minute)
        print('sleep done')

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Fanfare(bot))
```

Here is the result of the troubleshooting prints :

```
2023-02-08 13:47:56.568279
2023-02-08 13:48:00
```

Which seems normal to me.

However, the `'sleep done'` never appears, even after waiting. It seems like discord is sleeping forever

Comment: Which version of discord.py are you using it seems you are under version 2.
You can see the [migration guide here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html). Otherwise I've tested it out, running on discord.py 2.1.0 and it works.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using 1.7.3. I didn't think that it would be an issue since that's a stable version. I'll try with a later version